# Audio stops streaming after a while

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Just start streaming audio...starts playing, buffer goes ahead, but suddenly stops. When song catches up to the buffer, music stops. Pressing next goes to the nest songs but same thing happens. any idea?

```
private void startPlay(String file, String name) 
    {
        Log.i("Selected: ", file);

        tv_selelctedFile.setText(name);

        //progressControlSeekbar.setProgress(0);

        int maxVolume = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        int curVolume = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

        progressControlSeekbar.setMax(maxVolume);
        progressControlSeekbar.setProgress(curVolume);
        progressControlSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
            {
                isMoveingSeekBar = false;
            }
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
            {
                isMoveingSeekBar = true;
            }
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) 
            {
                if(isMoveingSeekBar)
                {
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                    Log.i("OnSeekBarChangeListener","onProgressChanged");
                }
            }
        });     

        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(file);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        progressControlSeekbar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);

        updatePosition();

        isStarted = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can try doing is
use the listeners instead of directly calling

```
 mediaPlayer.prepare();//use preapareAsync()
 mediaPlayer.start(); // dont call it here.
```

call the `OnPreparedListener()` of the mediaplayer and in `onPrepared()` use the `mediaplayer.start()`

if that doesn't help , just implement all the listeners for Media player, like `onComplete` `onError()` and check which one is called when suddenly media player stops playing

Hope it helps.